# How to derive that $\delta w = - PdV$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, ideal-gas, volume

I am not understanding how to derive this particular expression, which relates the inexact differential of work to the exact differential of volume,
$$\delta w = -PdV $$

**My attempt:**

Reversible work can be defined as:
$$w=-\int P dV  $$
First, I integrate both sides with respect to volume,
$$\frac{d}{dV}(w)=-\frac{d}{dV}(\int P dV) $$
$$ \frac{dw}{dV}=-P $$
Since the differential of work is inexact:
$$ \delta w=-PdV $$
Mathematically, I am unsure about my first step. Nonetheless, this was my approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you've gone round in a circle. What's wrong with this simple argument?

Suppose that the fluid exerts a force $F_n$ on a small area $A$ of the container wall, in a direction normal to that area. If that area moves outwards by a small distance $\Delta x$ normal to $A$ then the work done by the fluid on $A$ will be
$$\delta w=F_n \Delta x=\frac{F_n}{A} \times A \Delta x = p \Delta V.$$
We are not in any way assuming that $\delta w$ is a differential of some function of state, so there is no suspicion that $\delta w$ is an exact differential.

Comment: Your explanation for work makes sense and I see where Δ comes from. I think I am confused about the difference between  (the differential of ) and . I always thought work was defined as  = Δ. So is  =  Δ an equivalent statement?

Comment: @Sarthak Girdhar " is mostly used for a change, and this change in work makes no sense obviously" I agree, My use of $\delta w$ was an uneasy compromise. I wanted  a symbol for a small quantity (of work) but not for an increment of work, as if work were some function of state. That's why I kept off $dw$, but I agree that  $\delta w$ is not ideal notation. Zemansky in his wonderful 1950s (?) thermodynamics textbook used a special symbol, $dW$ in which the up-stroke of the d had a horizontal bar through it to mean a small amount of work but not an increment of a larger quantity, 'work'.